# How to put a link in my route title?

Tags: 8, routes

In my custom module `amap`, I have `amap.routing.yml` with (among others) this route:

```
amap.distribution_inscription_many_form:
  path: '/amap/editPlanningMany'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\amap\Form\DistributionInscriptionManyForm'
    _title: 'Update Planning'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'edit distribution inscription entities'
```

I'd like to have a link in the title of the route, something like
`Update Planning <a href="/amap/editPlanningOne">Click here</a>`

Drupal 8 API documentation says in [Structure of routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes)

> _title: The page title for the route. It may differ from the menu link title.
>   _title_arguments: Additional arguments for the title text passed along to t().
>   _title_context: Additional context information for the title text passed along to t().
>   _title_callback: A PHP callable (typically classname::method) returning the page title for the route.

but I don't know how to use it...
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you routing.yml change _title to _title_callback as below:

```
amap.distribution_inscription_many_form:
  path: '/amap/editPlanningMany'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\amap\Form\DistributionInscriptionManyForm'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\amap\Controller\TitleController::title'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'edit distribution inscription entities'
```

Create a "TitleController" controller in you amap module unser "src/Controller"

**TitleController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\amap\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class TitleController extends ControllerBase {

  public function title() {
    return t('Update Planning <a href="/amap/editPlanningOne">Click here</a>');
  }

}
```

Now your title will be callable from the controller and you can give whatever that likes you here.

Comment: I tried something like `return t('Update Planning') . ' ' . t('<a href="/amap/editPlanningOne">Click here</a>');`  
and it doesn't work! Any idea why?

Comment: IMO you have to use only one t() to render proper URL.